# ASP.NET WebMethod returning object as json but not in response method

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a simple webmethod:

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Does something.")> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function ReturnJSONData() As Person
    Dim guy As New Person
    guy.Name = "Joe"
    guy.Age = 8
    Return guy
End Function
```

and here is where I am calling the ajax method:

```
 function GetPerson() {
     PageMethods.ReturnJSONData(OnWSRequestComplete1);
 }
 function OnWSRequestComplete1(result) {
     alert(result.d);
 }
```

When I use a tool like firebug, I can see the JSON results:

```
{"d":{"__type":"Person","Name":"Joe","Age":8}}
```

However, when I call the "alert(result.d)" I get undefined.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Make sure `result` isn't a JSON *string*. If it is, you'll need to parse it into an object first (`JSON.parse`).

Answer (score 0):

When you get a response from a WebMethod, you need to eval the response because it is returned as a string. I'd hesitate against using `eval` in your code because the security risks.

If you're using jQuery you can call `jQuery.parseJSON(result)` which will return the actual Javascript object you expect.

Comment: I tried using alert(jQUery.parseJSON(result)); and now it is showing as null in my alert popup?  But my results when debugging still appear as above.  I'm not sure if this helps trouble shoot any of the issue, but when I look at the Response headers, it states that the Content-Type is "application/json; charset=utf-8" which is what I would expect, however I still can't see the JSON in an alert window.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `null` seems like a very weird return value since it should throw an exception if it can't parse it.

Comment: That's really really odd behavior. I can 't place my finger on it, but that has worked on in the past for me. How are you pulling the debugging values? Stright from the HTTP response? Or through a javascript debugger somewhere?

Comment: Just using the developer tool in Internet Explorer

Comment: This is very dangerous, don't use in a production environment, but what's the response when you do `eval('(' + result + ')');`?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I tried eval('(' + result + ')'); but got an error from visual studio "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Expected ']'"

Comment: When I call alert(result); I do get [Object object], but I still don't think there is any thing in that object?

Comment: Ah, that's progress, that means that result is an object. Try `result.d.__type` or `result.d.Name` and it should result in the data you're looking for.

Comment: Hmmm, I get an error that "Unable to get value of the property '__type': object is null or undefined". and using result.d.Name throws the same error.

Comment: Well I'm about to give up.  I tried the call using jQuery ajax call and it works fine?????

Comment: That was going to be my next idea. Could always answer your own question to help others!